# How to remove Couchbase node, having non replicated ephemeral bucket

Tags: couchbase

I am having 2 Couchbase node, having 3 ephemeral buckets. The buckets are non replicated.
Lets name the nodes as **A** and **B**. Now I want to keep node **B** and remove node **A**.
Our client services is having the IP of node **B**, so I want to remove node A. 
Can I remove node **A** directly from the Couchbase console and perform rebalancing. Am I going to lose data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this locally:

1. I created an ephemeral bucket with 0 replicas on a 2-node cluster.
2. I put 6 total documents in the bucket.
3. I [removed](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/manage/manage-nodes/remove-node-and-rebalance.html#remove-a-node-with-the-ui) one node.
4. I rebalanced the cluster.

After the rebalance was complete, I still had 6 documents in the ephemeral bucket.

So it appears that you will NOT lose data. HOWEVER, I would highly recommend taking advantage of the distributed nature of Couchbase and turn on replication in order to get high availability (in case something goes wrong with one of the nodes that you *didn't* plan for).

Comment: was able to replicate it in dev, got the same result, thanks for the answer.